# iOS - Problems with implementing a Delegate Reference using a singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, reference, delegates, singleton

I'm quite new to obj-c and currently reworking some existing code where a lot of singletons are used that caused random crashes. I managed to replace most of them with proper protocols but still struggle with setting up the reference on ONE delegate. I've read some posts here about singletons and protocols and also referred to the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) but the more I read the more I get confused. I assume that there is a side effect I'm not aware of - can someone please help to understand.

What I would need to set the delegate reference is the ID (pointer address) of the PlayerInterface instance.

Here is what I did so far:

```
// define delegate in DocumentsViewController.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <documentsProtocol> delegate;
```

and

```
// in DocumentsViewController.m
// set delegate reference using singleton
self.delegate = [PlayerInterface sharedInstance]; // here it crashes!
```

Here is the current problem I'm facing, when I set the delegate reference by a singleton it crashes on the thread. The ARC feature is turned on!

[crash-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDxvN.png)

For the singleton I'm using:

```
// in PlayerInterface.m (NSObject)
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

/// 1.EDIT ///

I was asked about the init of the singleton - in my MainViewController.m the PlayerInterface object is instantiated the first time:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.player = [PlayerInterface sharedInstance];
}
```

I've also tried to avoid the dispatch_once:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    PlayerInterface *play = [[PlayerInterface alloc] init];
    self.player = play;
}
```

But makes no difference ... also crashing! Anyone who can help?

/// 2.EDIT ///

I've tried a strange workaround: When instantiate the PlayerInterface the first time I make the ID a global variable (I know that this is against the idea of object orientated programming).

```
extern id play;
```

When it comes to the delegation I can now easy set the reference by using:

```
self.delegate = play;
```

It works like a charm, just good old C-Style :)

I assume that the problems with the singleton are based on the fact that I have three objects that communicating with each other. I will re-route the communication to a "star-type" to see if this helps.

Comment: 1) What's the error from the crash? 2) Delegates and singletons have nothing to do with each other. They are two completely separate and independent concepts. 3) Why are you using `@synthesize`? Do not follow any outdated tutorial that makes use of `@synthesize` (in most cases).

Comment: +1 for not using synthesize. The code you present has no crash. There could be something wrong in the init of the `PlayerInterface` object.

Comment: +1 for the crash log. There is very little we can advise without knowing more about the crash itself. As @CharlesThierry said above, the code you posted above doesn't actually show any potential crash so it looks to be somewhere else. But as a note; Singletons should have limited use, a lot of the time they cause more issues than they are worth so just be careful.

Comment: Please also set an exception breakpoint and share the source surrounding the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy :I've added the crash-log to the post. Regarding synthesize: I saw it in some tuts (maybe it's outdated) makes no difference if in or not. My main question was "how to get the ID of the PlayerInstance without the use of singletons. Maybe some can give me a hint?

Comment: The problem is inside the `dispatch_once` call. Update your question with the `init` method of your singleton. Make sure the `init` method doesn't directly or indirectly result in any access to the `sharedInstance` method.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated my question and hope I understand you correct. I've tried to avoid the sharedInstance when I instantiate the class - but no difference .. see above code!

Answer (score 0):

A delegate is simply an object that can be interrogated for ID's and other properties like any other object. Add to your "documentsProtocol" a "tellMeYourID" method and you're in business.

Comment: I think this is a "chicken/egg" problem ... how to set a delegate reference with the instance ID without knowing it!?

Comment: What do you mean by "instance ID"? You seem to attach a different meaning to it than I do.

Answer (score 0):

I had three objects that communicating with each other through protocols. Even if I paid attention not to end up in a delegation loop it seems that this caused the problem. After re-route the communication to a "star-type" all problems are gone. Now each object is just communicating with one other object. The MainViewController is the master in the middle and if I need to pass information I added a short method like:

```
// passing through MainVC to keep star type communication
- (void)updateList:(NSArray)list { 
    [self.player setList:list];
}
```

I don't know if this is the perfect solution, but much better than using a global variable that holds the ID of the player instance :)